# Clipping a div to 2 background images, then layering a gradient on top, with CSS3

Tags: layout, html, css

I want to be able to create a row of DIVs, like below:

```
\---------\---------\---------\
 \         \         \         \
 /         /         /         /
/---------/---------/---------/
```

The only thing is, each of these DIVs have a width of a percentage not absolute values.
I want to be able to create a DIV like above using two images...

```
\---+
 \  |
 /  |
/---+
```

and...

```
+--\
|   \
|   /
+--/
```

...where the first image is aligned to the left of the DIV and the second is aligned to the  right. Then, on top of this I want to add a gradient which goes into a NorthWest direction to SouthEast.

I want to try and avoid creating a DIV with 3 separate DIVs inside it, one for each section of the image, as I think CSS3 is evolving to stop this exact reason, something like the old days of giving a div a grid of 9 DIVs inside it just to add a nice outer shadow.

Anyway, does anyone know how I could do this? I realise there is such thing as background layering so I suppose that's a start.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have a look at the `:before` and `:after` pseudoclasses. They're supported pretty well IIRC.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I did look at them, it seems they can only really add content rather than a side-by-side div though

Comment: If you set `content: ""`, then you can give them a width and height, and a `background-image`, or gradient.

Comment: It seems that you can't have an empty string for `content: ""`

Comment: You can, but then you have to set a width and height to override the defaults of `auto`, which will give it no dimension.

Comment: I have added a width and height too, is it possible that the problem is with the `position: relative`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for some thing like this ..,

http://jsfiddle.net/HsZbp/1/

I have mentioned 3 backgrounds in one Div [Left right and center].

Comment: Uses multiple bg images, which isn't supported by IE8 or earlier.

Comment: This is the kind of thing i wanted, and I'm only interested in HTML5 technologies with the idea that if they want to view the web app, they will have to upgrade their browser. My issue is focused now around positioning the Divs (like above where the Divs overlap each other).

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to use 3 images instead of 2: one for the left of the container, one for the right of the container, and one (the new one) for the two middle borders. There would be left, right, and middle border images.

Each column would have a single bg image (left, middle, middle, respectively) with `background-position:left top;` and the outer container would have a single bg image (right) with `background-position:right top;`.